# @Autowired and PropertyPlaceholder

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to add a property from PropertyPlaceholder to a bean via @Autowired? I can't inject it in the xml-context-config because the beans are loaded this way:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="..."/>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In spring 3.0 (I think from Milestone 3) you can use @Value("${foo.bar}") to access properties from PropertyPlaceholder.

Comment: can you give me an example for this? i am using spring 3 rc3 and when i try this way (e.g. @Value("${foo.bar}") ) then my attribute gets the value "foo.bar" ...

Comment: Yes, lets say you have property placeholder configured like this:  
`<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:app.properties"/>`  
you can inject the value of property with key `foo.bar` from `app.properties` to you bean:  
`class MyBean {  
   @Value(${"foo.bar"} 
   private String value; 
}`

Answer (score 6):

A spring 2.5 approach:

```
@Component
public class Foo {
    @Autowired 
    @Qualifier("myFlag")
    private Boolean flag;
    /* ... */
}
```

and the context

```
<context:component-scan base-package="..."/>
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:app.properties"/>
<!-- the flag bean -->
<bean id="myFlag" class="java.lang.Boolean">
    <constructor-arg value="${foo.bar}"/>
</bean>
```

Cheers

Comment: +1 alternatively, and a bit less verbosely, `@Resource(name="myFlag")`